# How to clear textfield value in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I've developed a textInput composable with a trailing icon, and I'd like to clear the textInput when the icon is clicked. How can I access the textInput value, so that I can clear it?

```
    @Composable
fun TextInput(
    myVal: String,
    label: String,
    placeholder: String="",
    helperText: String="",
    errorText: String="",
    onValueChange : (String) -> Unit){
    val hasError = !errorText.isNullOrEmpty()
    val helperColor =  if (hasError)
        Color(0xFFfe392f)
        else
            Color(0xFF5c6a79)

    Row() {
            Column() {
                TextField(
                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                        textColor = Color(0xFF011e41),
                        cursorColor = Color(0xFF011e41),
                        focusedLabelColor = Color(0xFF011e41),
                        unfocusedLabelColor = Color(0xFF011e41),
                        unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color(0xFFebeced),
                        focusedIndicatorColor = Color(0xFF011e41),
                        errorCursorColor = Color(0xFFfe392f),
                        errorIndicatorColor = Color(0xFFfe392f),
                        errorLabelColor = Color(0xFFfe392f)
                    ),
                    value = myVal,
                    onValueChange = onValueChange,
                    label = { Text(label) },
                    placeholder = { Text(placeholder) },
                    isError = hasError,
                    trailingIcon = {Icon(Icons.Filled.Email, contentDescription = "sdsd", modifier = Modifier.offset(x= 10.dp).clickable {
                       //What should I do here?
                    })}
                )

                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                    text = if (hasError) errorText else helperText,
                    fontSize = 12.sp,
                    color = helperColor,
                )
            }
    }
}
```

it's used like this:

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
                    TextInput(myVal = text, label = "label", helperText = "", errorText = "my error") {text = it}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

the click handler of your trailing icon has to call the TextField's onValueChange with an empty string:

```kotlin
...
trailingIcon = { 
    Icon(
        Icons.Filled.Email,
        contentDescription = "sdsd",
        modifier = Modifier
            .offset(x= 10.dp)
            .clickable {
                //just send an update that the field is now empty
                onValueChange("") 
            }
        )
}
...
```

Comment: Elegant and logical

Answer (score 26):

You can use the **`trailingIcon`** attribute with a custom `clickable` modifier.
Something like:

```
var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    trailingIcon = {
        Icon(Icons.Default.Clear,
            contentDescription = "clear text",
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {
                    text = ""
                }
        )
    }
)
```

[image]

If you are using a `TextFieldValue`:

```
val content = "content"
var text by rememberSaveable(stateSaver = TextFieldValue.Saver) {
    mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(content))
}

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    trailingIcon = {
        Icon(Icons.Default.Clear,
            contentDescription = "clear text",
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {
                    text = TextFieldValue("")
                }
        )
    }
)
```

Comment: This only works if the text variable refers to a string. If it is a TextFieldValue object, this won't work. TextFieldValue is needed for cases where you need to manipulate the cursor such as placing it at the end of the text.

Comment: @Johann In this case you have just to use a different code in the `clickable` modifier of the `trailingIcon`. Answer updated.

Answer (score 5):

Use `trailingIcon` Composable property with `IconButton` to match the background selector of the icon with the rest of the theme. You can also put empty condition to display it only when there is some input in the text field.

Below is sample code snippet:

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf ("") }

TextField(
    trailingIcon = {
        when {
            text.isNotEmpty() -> IconButton(onClick = {
                text = ""
            }) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.Clear,
                    contentDescription = "Clear"
                )
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: A correct answer. It hides the icon when no text is written.

Answer (score 0):

This shall achieve this

```
//Caller
val text by remember { mutableStateOf (...) }

TextInput(text, ..., ...,)
```

```
//Composable
@Composable
fun TextInput(text, ..., ...){
val textState by remember { mutableStateOf (text) }
TextField(
 value = textState,
trailingIcon = {
 Icon(..., Modifier.clickable { textState = "" })
}
}
```